# In VS2010 the configuration list in Project Property Pages does not match the one in Configuration manager. How do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an old Visual Studio 2010 Project with *a lot* of configurations. In an effort to refactor/make sense of the project I decided to shuffle around and re-name some of those configurations (Using the `Edit` option in the Configuration Manager). The problem? The list of the configurations available in the Project Property Pages (where one can change compiler or linker options etc.) still displays the old names! This can be very confusing and the lack of consistency is infuriating.

I tried restarting Visual Studio and deleting the .user and .sdf files - those didn't help. I even tried to manually Search&Replace the old names with new ones in .vcxproj and .sln files. The only result of that was being unable to open the project properly (does not build).

Is there anything I have done wrong? Can I do anything to restore some order into this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the behaviour I described is a bug in Visual Studio 2010 but I have eventually found a way to do what I wanted despite it.

In order to fully change the name of a Project/Solution Configuration:

1. Open Configuration Manager
2. Select `<Edit...>` from the "Active solution configuration" drop-down list
3. Change the name of the configuration you want to edit and close the Edit Solution Configurations window
4. In the "Project contexts" section of Configuration Manager, open the "Configuration" drop-down list. You will notice that the configuration which name you've just changed still has it's old one there. Select `<Edit...>` once again and change it to whatever you did in step 3.
5. Visual Studio will notify you in an error prompt that "The operation could not be completed". This is (partially) wrong.
6. Close the prompt, the Configuration Manager and finally close the solution (from the `File` menu) saving any changes to it.
7. Re-open the solution.
8. Go into the Configuration Manager and once again inspect the relevant "Configuration" drop down in the "Project contexts" menu. You will notice that although initially the old configuration name is displayed, the drop down figures only the new one. Select it. Otherwise attempting to access Project Properties will now generate another "The operation could not be completed" error.
9. The configuration should now function under its new name.